# How do i use proxy in web3py?

Tags: python, web3py

I'm currently using this method to connect to web3py

```
infura_url = "https://node.node/asdasdasdasdasd/bsc/mainnet/archive/" # fast
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
```

How do I enable proxy? say i have proxy at '321.123.121.123:8081'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I = "http://aaa:bbb@111.11.1.1:20000a"
infura_url = "https://zzzz.io/kkkk/bsc/mainnet/archive/" # fast
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url,request_kwargs={"proxies":{'https' : I, 'http' : I }}))
```

Comment: Could you link to the documentation? This would help add some context to your answer :)

Comment: you can find the documentation here (link): https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/providers.html#httpprovider

Answer (score 0):

You can also use web3-proxy-providers, which is a python package for connecting to HTTP and WebSocket Json-RPC using Socks and HTTP proxies

run

```
pip install web3-proxy-providers
```

code

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3_proxy_providers import HttpWithProxyProvider

provider = HttpWithProxyProvider(
    endpoint_uri='https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<YourAlchemyKey>',
    proxy_url='socks5h://localhost:1080'
)
web3 = Web3(
    provider=provider,
)
print(web3.eth.block_number)
```

Disclaimer: I am the owner of this package
https://github.com/sinarezaei/web3-proxy-providers

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using AsyncHTTPProvider, please consider that it is different than HTTPProvider. HTTPProvider uses `requests` module under the hood, however, AsyncHTTPProvider uses `aiohttp`. Hence, for `AsynHTTPProvider`, if you provide `proxies` keyword for `request_kwargs`, you will get `Error | ClientSession._request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies`. To fix it, use just `proxy` instead. It should look like below:

```py
AsyncWeb3.AsyncHTTPProvider(
   random.choice(RPC[chain]["rpc"]),
   request_kwargs={"proxy": "http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxyHost:proxyPort"},
)
```

I hope it helps